# Dynamic class creation for string grouping

Tags: java

Here is a sketch of the problem I want to solve:

- I need to group several strings under another one, so that there would be a way to include new strings into this "group"
- It has to be dynamic: I read those strings from a file and create the groups on the fly

Example:

Input file:

```
ANIMAL: DOG CAT BIRD
PERSON: CLAIRE DEMETRIOS NEIL
ANIMAL: CROCODILE BUTTERFLY
```

I would need to create a "group" (don't know if a class or a structure would be better) called ANIMAL (on the fly by the code) and include the five animals in there, taking into account we are dealing with text strings.

I am looking for a way to classify those strings and I wonder what the simplest and most efficient way would be: classes? structures? superstrings?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What have you tried? What were your problems? Show us your code, and tell us which part is not working.

Comment: Can you provide an example? It's hard to get what you want to achieve.

Comment: It's rather an orientation question, I would like to have others' opinion before getting down to coding, as I have never coded anything like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a Map with String key and List value like

```
HashMap<String, List<String>> hashmap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

List<String> arraylist = new ArrayList<String>();
arraylist.add("Hello");
arraylist.add("World.");

//Put list to a group
hashmap.put("mykey", arraylist);

//Dynamically add element to a group
hashmap.get("mykey").add("Everyone");

//Retrieve all element of a group
List<String> list = hashmap.get("mykey");
System.out.println(list);
```

This will output:

```
[Hello, World., Everyone]
```

### Update:

According to Carlos's comment, you can use a simple if-else block to dynamically create list. For example-

```
if (hashmap.containsKey("person")) {
  hashmap.get("person").add("Emdadul");
} else {
  List<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>();
  lst.add("Emdadul");
  hashmap.put("person", lst);
}
```

I hope it will solve your problem. Rest of logic should be implemented by you.

Comment: Thank you Emdadul:

- What is "mykey" ?
- How could the list be defined dynamically?

Comment: I tried to run your code but it returns: 

 type List does not take parameters
     HashMap<String, List<String> > hashmap = new HashMap<>();

Comment: you may using old version of java (java 6 or earlier). then use like this: HashMap<String, List<String>> hashmap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

Comment: "mykey" is just a group name, in your case it should be "Animal", "Person", etc. Please mark this as Correct Answer if it solve your problem.

Comment: I am sorry, I don't get HashMap<String, List<String>> hashmap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>(); working, same error.

I tried import java.util.Map; (I saw it in a different post) but it does not work either

Comment: you need to these: 
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
 (a good IDE should show them as suggestion)